# Collecting Akka actor system metrics

Tags: scala, akka, metrics

Scala 2.12 and Akka here, and pretty new to both. I'm trying to collect some metrics about my actor system at runtime. Specifically, I'm interested in:

- Getting the # of running actors in my actor system
- For each actor:

  - Getting the number of messages it has received
  - Getting the number of messages it has sent to other actors
  - Determining how long a message has been in the actor's mailbox
  - Determining how long the actor took to actually process the message
  - Getting the current size of the actor's mailbox
- Determining how many dead letters have been sent across the entire actor system

I'm hoping Akka has some kind of little known "meta API" where I can go to get these kinds of metrics, otherwise I'm probably going to have to wire up my own instrumentation/telemetry and do everything myself, in which case I'm wondering what that approach might look like?

I see Lightbend has an awesome [telemetry library](https://developer.lightbend.com/blog/2017-06-23-mtotm-akka-telemetry/index.html) but its commercial and I'm cheap :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe Kamon will help you. Here is a [documentation](http://kamon.io/documentation/1.x/instrumentation/akka/actor-system-metrics/) about metrics collection in Akka.